# Selenium: Firefox or Chrome

Tags: python, selenium

Что лучше использовать при работе с **selenium**, firefox или же chrome. Что занимает менее ресурсов и работает быстрее?

Answer (score 0):

Определенно firefox. Под этот браузер есть драйвер geckodriver, который тебе пригодится при работе с selenium

Comment: для chrome тоже есть драйвер. Почему вы предложили firefox?

Comment: Это мое мнение, я сам работал на firefox, и мне понравилось, не нужно долго париться, все быстро работает, а на chrome нужно подбирать, чтоб версия браузера и драйвера совпадала